# Allowing elasticsearch to insert dots in field names

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0

I am trying to insert data in elasticsearch (ver 2.3) which contains dot in the field names. The field names are pretty dynamic and nested which can contain all sorts of special characters too. Is it possible that I can get that kind of data inserted into elasticsearch. And how easy and efficient that would be?

Sample JSON that I am trying to insert:-

```
 {
  "v-5c": {
    "reg": "us1",
    "sTypes": {
      "app": [
        {
          "z": "us1b",
          "sId": "s-73f",
          "availableIps": 990
        },
        {
          "z": "us1a",
          "sId": "s-253",
          "availableIps": 1011
        }
      ]
    },
    "sgs": {
      "st": "sg-346",
      "lb-hps-xrks": "sgea1"
    },
    "cs": {
      "abc.xyz.xyz.com": "valu1",
      "abc-xyz_zyz.com": "value2"
    }
  }
}
```

The error that I am seeing is following:-

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"Field name [abc.xyz.xyz.com] cannot contain '.'"}],"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"Field name [abc.xyz.xyz.com] cannot contain '.'"},"status":400}
```

It would be really great that I would get to insert the field names with dot in it, or else any other solution is also acceptable. Pls suggest?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Dots are not allowed in field names in elasticsearch 2.0 See [elasticsearch commit - Enforce field names do not contain dot](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/12068) - Jul 7, 2015

But check elasticsearch 2.4, 5.0 - [Mappings: Allow to force dots in field names](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/19937) - Aug 11, 2016

Comment: Thanks, I am using AWS elasticsearch 2.3 and what is the options that are available to insert fields with dots in it?

Comment: You might want to use `-` or `/` in 2.3 instead of `.`. If its a new project, can you not use elasticsearch 2.4+?

Comment: Nopes it's not a new project. But I also see that in 2.4 or so internally with a dot in the field name, it converts them into object and stuff, which again looks dangerous while trying to get the id. Or it returns exactly the same way as it was indexed?